# Possible to attach a Blu-Ray writer to VirtualBox on Linux Mint 18 host?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, blu-ray

What I **don't** have:

- Windows on a machine

---

What I **do** have:

- Laptop with USB 3.0
- Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit OS (on this laptop)
- VirtualBox version 5.1.22 + Extension Pack (on this OS)
- Windows 8.1 guest machine (in this VirtualBox)

---

What I **need**:

I would like to know if to this setup, it will be possible to plug through a Blu-Ray writer and copy some of my original Blu-Ray disks?

---

**Rationale:**

On Linux it is highly complicated and often impossible to read original Blu-ray movie disks.

Comment: I don’t see why it wouldn’t be possible, but why bother? Linux should also be able to write BDs?

Comment: This is totally doable, I do it myself.  Debian Host, Windows 10 Guest, and i have all sorts of USB devices that I configure to expose to the Windows 10 Guest including a Blu-Ray writer, webcam, and scanner.  They all work perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is entirely possible with both the Linux Mint OS and the Virtual windows machine.

really all you need to do is make an ISO of your Blu-ray disk and save them anywhere you please.

You could also copy the actual media files depending on their format. And one last possibility is to use a screen capture program to record the videos. This however is not the best option as it could result in a choppy recording depending on your computers hardware and the software configurations. Still worth mentioning.

Edit:

There are some post out there about using blu-ray on Linux.
Take a look at this post. [Can linux play blu-rays?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565516/can-linux-play-blu-rays)

Comment: Reason for downvote? I do not think what I have sad is inaccurate so please let me know if it is.